Why does X server crash on certain web pages?
I'm using Void Linux.
In the recent time I have noticed, that when I open a new tab with certain link, but I do not know them a prior, everything is okay. But then, if I try to switch to that tab, or it opens automatically on the startup of a browser, whole X server goes down and crashes.
It happens the same way on Brave, Firefox and LibreWolf, so I suspect it is not caused by the browser (browser engine itself, but there is some underlying problem.)
Despite my best attempts, X doesn't show any errors in the log, dmesg as well, the only thing I was able to get my hands on is strace log from LibreWolf.
The only thing that I have noticed that was common between two of such webpages was that when I tried to curl -LO they, it both times returned with error saying that content length was not specified.
One of such retrieved links with Curl is this:
curl -LO https://docs.libretiny.eu/docs/dev/lt-api/

If anyone has ever encountered any such thing, please give me/us a way to solve it, or tell me if I should file a bug request.
